# confidence Interval of multivariate Gaussian Distribution

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have an single variable which is gaussian distributed (with mean value 0 and standard deviation sigma). Then I certainly know that there is 68.2% of the chance that this variable should lie between [-sigma, sigma].
Similarily I have an vector with dimension 1000 and every element of this vector can be seen as independent and gaussian distributed with the same sigma (mean value 0 for all). Then what is the probability that the vector lies within a hyperball with r = sigma? 
It would great if somebody can help me with that?

Now make this question more complicated
What if the signal itself is complex valued (the same mean and std for both real and imaginary part. We also assume the real and imaginary part are independent from each other). what is the possibility that the absolute value of the vector |v| lies within an hyperball with radius r?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looking for a confidence interval, but for the cumulative probability as a function of the distance from the mean. See [this paper](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Cumulative_function_n_dimensional_Gaussians_12.2013.pdf) for your answer, specifically page 8.