# Confidence ellipse for a 2D gaussian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

For a 1D gaussian, the interval +/- 1SD about the mean will comprise ~68% of the area under the curve.  Consider a 2D gaussian with a mean of zero and a diagonal covariance matrix (i.e., it is not rotated), with standard deviations $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$.  Consider the ellipse drawn to pass through the points $(\pm\sigma_x, 0)$ and $(0, \pm\sigma_y)$.  Will it also contain 68% of the volume underneath the 2D curve?  I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934179/confidence-interval-of-multivariate-gaussian-distribution) which asks a more general version of this question, but I couldn't immediately tell from the reference given what the answer was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe that the required probability $<\ \approx 0.68^2=0.4624$

Then observe that you might as well assume $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=1$, then your question becomes what is the probability that a point lies inside the unit circle. Then proceed by converting to polars, when:
$$
p=\int_{r=0}^1 f_R(r)\;dr=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}\; rdrd\theta=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}\approx 0.393
$$

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood, but it seems Wolfram Alpha disagrees?  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+integral&a=*C.solve+integral-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=exp%28-r%5E2%2F2%29*r%2F%282*pi%29&f=Integral.integrand_exp%28-r%5E2%2F2%29*r%2F%282*pi%29&a=*FVarOpt-_**Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend--) ...

Comment: ... and [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+integral&a=*C.solve+integral-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=exp(-r%5E2%2F2)%2F(2*pi)&f=Integral.integrand%5Cu005fexp(-r%5E2%2F2)%2F(2*pi)&f3=0&f=Integral.rangestart%5Cu005f0&f4=2*pi&f=Integral.rangeend_2*pi&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Integral.variable---.**Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend---)

Comment: @Matt You have lost a factor of $2\pi$ (the outer integral w.r.t. $\theta$), also a reality check should lead you to expect while the probability is less than $\approx 0.482..$ it should be reasonably close.

Comment: $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{r=0}^1\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}\; r\;dr\;d\theta=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\;d\theta\  \int_{r=0}^1\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-r^2/2}\; r\;dr = \int_{r=0}^1e^{-r^2/2}\; r\;dr$

Comment: OH I get it.  I was integrating wrt $r$ by mistake in the second integral.

Comment: Why did you claim that the required probability is the original probability of interest, squared? I think the whole point is whether the simple formula for 1-d extends gracefully to 2-d with the intuitive modifications suggested. (and I do like your way of simplifying down to a nice counterexample nugget)

Comment: @neuronet I didn't, I said the required probability was less than the square. That's because the probability of a point being in the square $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$ is greater than being in the unit disk because the former contains the latter. I did it to indicate the sort of value we should expect for the answer.